# How can I trigger a webhook to send product data to Zapier when a specific product is purchased in WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, zapier

I want to trigger a webhook that sends product data to Zapier (which creates a spreadsheet row in google docs) whenever a specific product is bought in my WooCommerce store. For context, I have a subscription membership form which takes customer details and then they purchase the subscription through a woocommerce add to cart. The form and the cart are not joined but the form is sent to zapier and then to spreadsheet (via Zapier) and I want to the cart to send the specific product data, i.e. 3 Year membership to zapier so that I can also record the customers membership period. I know this is a silly workaround but is this possible at all?

I have tried putting creating a webhook action in Woocommerce (advanced tab) however I do not know what the custom action should be or if this is the actual way to achieve this.

Comment: https://docs.om4.io/woocommerce-zapier/trigger-rules/